# Simplify calculating many similar values with slightly different methods? [Generic way]

Tags: c#, database, list, unity-game-engine, calculation

Imagine there is a `List` ***(ExampleList)*** with multiple values of the **same type** (*float, int, string,... Doesn't matter*).

Each value has to be calculated using *different kind of data* **and** ***slightly*** ***different type of calculations***.

To make it clear: **Each value in ExampleList is calculated differently**!

As an example:

The **ExampleList** has 100 integers, that are 0 at default. Each value at it's **specific index** is responsible for a **specific representation**. Let's say they represent some sort of **limit**. So maybe there are 100 different **molecules for example**, and each of them needs a **different amount of different ingredients** to make.

So each `method` is structured something like **this**:

```
void Method (IngredientData, someOtherIngredientData){ /*Calculation dependent on parameters, which is then directly set to the value in ExampleList*/}
```

Now the different values take different parameters, that could also be of any other type, and different calculations.

This has to happen once for each value when the *application gets opened* and everytime a *certain data* the calculation of a value used gets *changed*.

---

This could be archived by writing different `methods` for every value, which calculate the value and add it to the **ExampleList**.

I can think of **two ways** archiving this, but both are **suboptimal**.

1. Create a `class` with all the `methods` and assign them to **`events`** for the *start* of the application and for *everytime a data the calculation of a value needs gets changed*.

**Problem**: For `lists` with many values (*around 100 for example*) the `script` would get ***very big and confusing***, especially if some of the calculation methods are bigger...

2. Create some kind of `parentclass` and inherit a `childclass` for every value. That would make it easier to change the calculation for certain values.

**Problem**: Now the confusion is where the `scripts` are getting stored and assigned, as there would be around 100 *seperate Scripts* and also that would be a lot of *repetitive writing work*.

---

Is is possible to completely get rid of that confusion and do something like a `scriptable object` but with the possibility to not only modify the **values** but **also** the **methods**?

---

I am using **c#** and **Unity**

Comment: Is your `List` contents different values of the same type, or different types? If it is the latter then you can't really do this in C# unless you use an `List<object>` or `ArrayList` and then your are pinning value types (slow and unsafe).

Comment: Modified my question to make it more clear

Comment: Could you give a code example that demonstrates what you intend to achieve? It's unclear how you identify which calculation to use. Is it just: `if (val == 1) DoA(); else if (val == 2) DoB();`?

Comment: I feel we need a minimal code sample that demonstrates what you are trying to do, and where you are having difficulties.

Comment: What differentiates one calculation type from another one? Is the _position_ within the list, or is there an unspecified rule/dataset that describes the mapping?

Comment: There is a conflict here. If each value is to be calculated from a function, then why do you need to call the function when the value is changed (1st option) the value should always reflect the result a calculation and not be changed manually. Or is the calculation an initial value, and from then on the value will differ? Who controls what the values are, is it the functions or the user?

Comment: @JohnAlexiou The values of the ExampleList are used very often during runtime, so I am trying to calculate them as little as possible. The values in the List are dependent on data that is changed rarely, everytime it is changed tho the value needs to be updated. It was unclear in the initial question that I mean an event dependent on the change if a data, not in the change of the value

Comment: @Xerillio I edited my question and added a example, I think it should be clearer now

Comment: @unitydevelopmentquestions I'm sorry but you'll have to be more specific. Your explanations are too hypothetical to be understandable. Show us a proof of concept with examples (input list), how you check conditions and choose a method and what the result of executing that method should be as well as how you know when to execute it again. You seem to be asking how to optimize something but we haven't seen what a simple/naïve solution looks like yet.

Comment: @unitydevelopmentquestions it seems that you need a `Lazy<T>` for each value which is evaluated only once and cached afterwards automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I got the question right, but what you can do, without creating a class is just to declare an object list

```
List<object> MyList = new();
```

Then you can just do one function, with a for loop, and switch cases. And just make a static class for the external functions:

```
for(int i = 0; i < MyList.Count; i++)
{
     switch(MyList[i].GetType())
        {
            case typeof(int):
                 FunctionForIntegers(MyList[i]);
                 break;
        }
}
```

This solution is better than making a class for an object container, you just have now to declare functions for each object.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I edited my question to make it more clear that I need a different calculation for each value and that there is only one type of value in the list. Otherwise great answer